# How to represent elements of a field by a base with minimal coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Let $K:=\mathbb F_{p^{16}}=\mathbb F[x]/(x^{16}-2)$ be a finite field where $p$ is chosen, that this ring-extension is really a field. Now we take an element $A\in K$ and we want to compute

$$A^d \in \mathbb F_{p^{16}}$$

The easiest way to do this, is to split $d$ into a sum to the base $p$, that means
$$d = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{15} d_kp^k$$
where $d_k\in\mathbb Z \cap (-\delta, \delta)$  where $\delta \to 0$.

Since my special purpose is not depending on $d$ itselfe, I'm also looking for an integer $d'$, such that $d\mid d'$.

---

## Definition: Ideal integer

I will call an integer $d$ with coefficients $d_k$ ideal, if and only if the sum of the absolute values of all coeffcients is the minimal possible. That means:
$$d'' \text{ ideal }\Leftrightarrow \sum\limits_{k=0}^{15} |d''_k| = \min\left\{ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{15} |d'_k| : d'=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{^15} d'_k p^k\text{ and } d\mid d'\right\}$$

---

Now the **Question** is: Is there any algorithm, that solves the above problem, of finding an ideal integer?

I would think about interpreting this theory as a vector space and looking for minimal vectors. But I don't know anything about this problem.

Comment: I don't understand this. $p = 0$ in $K$ so that sum is just $0$. Or what does the expression $p^k$ mean? Also, $a_k$ "minimal" -- with respect to what order?

Comment: K has characteristic $p$. If $p=0$ K would not be a finite field. Therefore, $p$ has to be a prime (as defined by "prime power") bigger than or equal to 2. Since this question loses its sense, when we fix $p=2$, we will say any $p$ much bigger than anyone could say in words :) Just think about the range $p\in (2^{300}, 2^{30000})$.

Comment: One of us has a complete misunderstanding of finite fields. If your question makes no sense if you set $p=2$ (what about $p=3$?), then you should wonder if your question makes sense at all. -- One thought: Could it be that you mean the ring $\mathbb{Z}/ p^{16}$ (which is *not* a field)? In that circumstance there might be an interpretation in which your question does make sense.

Comment: Because $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbf{F}_2= \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the field with $4$ elements is $\mathbf{F}_4 = \mathbf{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1) = \{ a+bx, (a,b) \in \mathbf{F}_2\}$ with the addition $(a+bx)+(c+dx) = (a+c)+(b+d)x$ and the multiplication $(a+bx)(c+dx) = ac+bdx^2+ (ad+bc)x=ac+bd(x+1)+ (ad+bc)x$ $= (ac+bd)+ (ad+bc+bd)x$

Comment: I and others have asked the same question earlier, but you dodged the question. Exactly how do you interpret such a sum $A$ as an element of $K$? As an element of $K$ we have $p=0$, but this means just that the characteristic of $K$ is equal to $p$. The normal way (in algebra) of interpreting an integer $m$ as an element of a finite field is to think of it as 
$$m\cdot 1_K=1_K+1_K+\cdots+1_K$$ a sum of $m$ copies of $1_K$. And under that interpretation $p=0_K$ because a sum of $p$ ones is zero.

Comment: So you **must** mean something else. I know that in many computer implementations an element $b_0+b_1\alpha+\cdots +b_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}$ of $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ ($\alpha$ a zero of the defining polynomial) is stored internally as a sequence of bits $b_{n-1}\cdots b_2b_1b_0$, and some programmers write that out as the "integer"
$b_0+b_1\cdot2+b_2\cdot2^2+b_{n-1}\cdot2^{n-1}$. But, then the arithmetic of the field has nothing whatsoever to do with that of integers, so they never think of it as an actual base two integer.

Comment: So, one more time, what is the meaning of $\sum_ka_kp^k$ as an element of $\Bbb{F}_{p^{16}}$. Judging from your earlier questions I suspect that it may be somebody's notation for the element $\sum_k a_k\alpha^k$, where $\alpha$ is a zero of $x^{16}-2$ in an extension field of $\Bbb{F}_p$. But can you, please, confirm this and spell it out for us. **THIS NOTATION IS NOT STANDARD IN ALGEBRA. WE DO NOT UNDERSTAND!** You have asked potentially interesting questions, but I stopped reading them because this idiosyncratic notation blocks the way.

Comment: So in algebra we can write $\Bbb{F}_{p^{16}}=\Bbb{F}_p[x]/\langle x^{16}-2\rangle$ assuming that $p$ is chosen in such a way that $x^{16}-2$ is irreducible. But what on Earth is the meaning of $A$ here?

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Let me rephrase the question. I'm considering the field $$\mathbb F_{p^{16}}=\mathbb F[x]/(x^{16}-2)$$. At this point I see, that I wrote some kind of garbage in the thread. :D Over that field I'm interested in exponentiation by big integers. The easiest way is, to represent any exponent as a sum to the base $p$. Since $p^k$-Frobenius endomorphisms are easily computed. Lets say we want to compute $$A^d \in \mathbb F_{p^{16}}$$ and, therefore, wants to find a representation $$d=\sum d_k p^k$$ where any $d_k\in\mathbb Z$ is chosen to be as close as possible at zero.

Comment: Maybe I was not able to understand the comment at that time well, or just was to confused in general. Now, I hope, that this question is more clear.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I misunderstood your comment. So I've read "p=0" instead of "p=0 in K". So you're totaly right. I rephrased my (basically) faulty question, to a (hopefully) more clear one.

Comment: @Shalec: Your rephrased question initially made more sense to me, but now I'm lost again. It seems as if you want a "minimal" representation of the residue class of an integer $d$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^{16}$ now. Well for that you have to choose all $d_k$ from sets whose residues make up $\mathbb{Z}/p$, and it seems to me that you can minimise your absolute value sum by taking (for odd $p$)  $\{(1-p)/2, (3-p)/2,..., -1, 0, 1, ... (p+1)/2\}$ as representatives. However, if you allow *any* multiples, I can just take $d' = p^{16}d$ and have all $d'_k = 0$. So that cannot be what you mean either.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg yes, you are right. This is not, what I supposed to get. Say I have a base-two representation of an integer, only with positiv coefficients. This representation can be better written by negativ and positiv coefficients. Now we consider the prime $p$ again. The representation is a polynomial over $p$ with large coefficients (say ~ $2^{64}$) but there is a way, to multiply this, and reduce all coefficients, closely to one, but increasing the degree of that polynomial. If we assume, that powers of $p$ are computed for free, but the others not, it's our aim to reduce the coeffi

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I understood your point and saw my error. I'm looking for a method, applied on polynomial-likes" that increases the power but reduces the coefficients. Say $u=u_3p^3 + u_2p^2 + u_1p + u_0$ where $u_i \sim 2^{64}$ but when applying that method, we get $\alpha u=u'=u'_np^n+...+u'_0$ with $|u'_i| << 2^{64}$

But in all cases it has to be: $r\not\mid d''$, where in the upper case $d''=u'$. The aim is to reduce the cost for exponentiation, under the assumption, that powers to "powers of $p$ are free.

Comment: @Shalec: OK, new attempt. It seems that the "16" is arbitrary then and what you are asking for is sort of minimal (in absolute value) representatives in a $p$-adic expansion of an integer $d$. I still think that my above set of representatives from $\frac{1-p}{2}$ to $\frac{p+1}{2}$ (note that half of them are negative) solves this problem for an individual integer $d$. Now, ask for the smallest sum of abs. val. of rep. for *any (non-zero) multiple of $d$*, then that is either 1 if $d$ is a power of $p$ (obviously) and in all other cases, 2.

Comment: (cont'd) Namely, let $d=e\cdot p^k$ for $p\nmid e$. Then by little Fermat/Euler, $e | (p^{\varphi(e)}−1)$ for the totient function $\varphi$, so you get your "ideal integer" $d''$ as $\frac{p^{\varphi(e)}−1}{e}\cdot d=(−1)\cdot p^k+1⋅p^{\varphi(e)+k}$ with $|−1|+|1|=2$. That is, if I understand you correctly. (Btw, in my earlier comments, the representatives only need to go until $\frac{p-1}{2}$; I miscounted due to the old fencepost problem.)